# Difference between NP-Hard and NP-Complete

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, np

Can someone please summarize the exact difference between NP-Complete and NP-Hard problems in simple language? Wiki and my standard books aren't exactly helping.

Comment: too elementary (defined very well on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and in any decent introduction to complexity book), voting to close.

Comment: To voters: when you vote to close as too elementary, please consider to [use “too localized” instead of “off topic” as a reason](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/356/the-reason-to-close-too-elementary-questions).

Comment: @chronoz, I would highly recommend reading [the site's FAQ](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science) if you have any questions about why this question was closed, especially [this](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/361#361) and [this](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/235#235).

Answer (score 2):

A NP-complete problem is an NP-hard problem which is in NP.

Comment: Figured I'd slip in a quick comment, in case it helps the OP, before the question is closed for being too elementary: Monoid's answer is the correct definition. Some further, natural implications: Any problem harder than an NP-complete problem is NP-hard; NP-complete problems are NP-hard; any problem easier than an NP-complete problem is *not* NP-hard.